# Erro de não inicialização

Tags: c, ponteiro, tipagem

Estou a ter um erro de não inicialização, e não consigo perceber porque:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  const int LENGTH = 10;
  const int WIDTH = 5;
  const char NEWLINE = "\n";
  int area;
  area = LENGHT * WIDTH;
  printf("Value of area : %d", area);
  printf("%c", NEWLINE);
  return 0;
}
```

Erros:

> ```
> C:\Users\zegla\OneDrive\Ambiente de Trabalho\Cexs\trainning6_const.c: In function 'main':
> C:\Users\zegla\OneDrive\Ambiente de Trabalho\Cexs\trainning6_const.c:6:24: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
>    const char NEWLINE = "\n";
>                         ^
> C:\Users\zegla\OneDrive\Ambiente de Trabalho\Cexs\trainning6_const.c:9:10: error: 'LENGHT' undeclared (first use in this function)
>    area = LENGHT * WIDTH;
>           ^
> C:\Users\zegla\OneDrive\Ambiente de Trabalho\Cexs\trainning6_const.c:9:10: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
> ```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Tem dois erros, um é de digitação, a variável `LENGTH` está escrita errado.

O outro erro é que está tentando guardar um endereço para uma *string* em uma variável que não é uma *string*. Ela precisaria ser um ponteiro para suportar o que deseja.

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main(){
    const int LENGTH = 10;
    const int WIDTH = 5;
    const char *NEWLINE = "\n";
    int area;
    area = LENGTH * WIDTH;
    printf("Value of area : %d", area);
    printf("%c", NEWLINE);
    return 0;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/GzvFXz). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/jhtiyjwb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/VariableXLiteral.c).

Nos IDEs *online* eu fiz um pouco melhor e diferente em cada caso.

Geralmente não se faz assim, ainda que todo este código seja desnecessário, então é até complicado dizer o que poderia ser melhor, já que melhor mesmo seria fazer tudo diferente. Pode acabar ficando com vícios de programação fazendo desta forma. Este código produz o mesmo resultado com uma linha.

Comment: Não deveria ser `printf("%s", NEWLINE);` ao invés de `%c`?

Comment: @gato Deveria, mas tem tanto erro aí, que uma a mais não faz diferença, o importante é que compilou e rodou :) Fazer certo tiraria tudo isto, já que o código não faz sentido. Sei que é para aprender, mas é melhor aprender com coisas mais realistas. Melhorei a resposta dando alternativas.